# Wireless WIFI Singnal range Under a Cellphone Tower

Tags: wireless

There is a company who has a Cellphone tower in the back lot, about 300 ft from the building. The Wifi(n signal) network is inside the building about 20 ft from the side door, and with a cellphone they can not keep the Wifi signal more then 10ft outside that side door.

What is the cell phone tower doing to the Wifi Signal? They want to install Wifi Cameras to watch a gas tank and some other equipment.

Would installing an outdoor range extender even help with this, or would the cellphone tower keep it contained to a small area?

Is there anywhere to read on cell phones and the effect on Wifi signals?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wifi and cellular telephones use two completely different frequency bands, so your problem has nothing to do with the cell tower.  An outdoor antenna and/or a more powerful access point will help your coverage outside.

Comment: Thinking it might be because the building it all metal then? There is a creek next to it as well on the other side.

Comment: A metal building would certainly be a factor. All the more reason to use external antennas placed outside. The tower, creek, etc. are too far away to have much effect.

Comment: Would also suggest adding an external access point in a weatherproof enclosure, if cost allows. In this case, considering the metal building, I'd suggest running a network cable to the device rather than trying to wifi mesh it.

Comment: It was found, besides being a metal barn, there is a creek under the entire plot of land. Wifi is out of the question for them.